# How can I rewrite URL's of a certain directory?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

Ok, vague question title, I know.  Wasn't sure how to summarize this in one line.  I have two applications in my CodeIgniter installation: frontend and admin.  There are two front controllers for each that set to the correct application folder.  Currently, I use index.php/home for the home page of the frontend and admin.php/home for the home page of the admin panel.

I finally got around to removing index.php from the URL of the frontend.  For the admin cp, I would like to use example.com/admin instead of example.com/admin.php.  So I basically need to rewrite any uri that has admin as the first segment to admin.php.  I figured that adding `RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admin.php/$1` to my htaccess would do the trick, but apparently it doesn't... Not completely anyway.  I get 404 Page Not Found for every single page in my admin cp.  What am I doing wrong?

```
# Deny OR Allow Folder Indexes.
# Since we disable access to PHP files you 
# can leave this on without worries. 
# OR better yet, create a .htaccess file in
# the dir you want to allow browsing and
# set it to +Indexes
Options -Indexes

Options +FollowSymLinks

# Set the default file for indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # mod_rewrite rules
    RewriteEngine on

    # The RewriteBase of the system (if you are using this sytem in a sub-folder).
    # RewriteBase /CodeIgniter_1.6.3/

    # This will make the site only accessible without the "www." 
    # (which will keep the subdomain-sensive config file happy)
    # If you want the site to be accessed WITH the "www." 
    # comment-out the following two lines.
    # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
    # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

    # If a controler can't be found - then issue a 404 error from PHP
    # Error messages (via the "error" plugin)
    # ErrorDocument 403 /index.php/403/
    # ErrorDocument 404 /index.php/404/
    # ErrorDocument 500 /index.php/500/

    # Deny any people (or bots) from the following sites: (to stop spam comments)
    # RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} nienschanz\.ru [NC,OR]
    # RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} porn\.com
    # RewriteRule .* - [F]
    # Note: if you are having trouble from a certain URL just 
    # add it above to forbide all visitors from that site.

    # You can also uncomment this if you know the IP:
    # Deny from 192.168.1.1

    # If the file is NOT the index.php file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
    # Hide all PHP files so none can be accessed by HTTP
    RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ index.php/$1

    # If the file/dir is NOT real go to index
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admin.php/$1

</IfModule>

# If Mod_ewrite is NOT installed go to index.php
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please enable the [RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog), increase the log level, and post the log file after trying again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your rule **before** you index.php routing rule. It's because `^(.*)$` is matching `admin/whatever`, so your admin rule will never get executed. You should also add `-Multiviews` to your options so it looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews
```

Then right under `RewriteEngine On`, add your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admin.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I'm still getting a 404 not found error for every single page under /admin.